# How to iterate through folder of files on GitHub using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

I want to be able to iterate through a local folder of files (CSVs) on GitHub and use the file contents in Javascript. I used this code but it only retrieves the contents of one file:

```
var array = [];
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
file.onreadystatechange = function () {
   array.push(this.responseText);
}
file.open("GET", "[csv link]", true);
```

I read through other questions, and the suggested method was to use PHP, but because I am going to be using this for GitHub pages, PHP isn't supported. Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: This is a rough resource https://gist.github.com/cowboy/777bdf8eb9b757691346

Comment: In order to help you, can you please confirm if I understand correctly your question:
1. You want to be able to fetch some files from a GitHub repository from a GitHub page that has some javascript code (like your example)
2. is that repository public?